# Parse : How to send a push notification to everyone from iOS app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

is there a way to send a push notification to everyone directly from app, as in the console ?
if i try following code :

```
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setMessage:@"Invio Push"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

looking at the consolle
it says that has been sent to 0 users,and it tried to send to channels i/o everyone.
If i send the message from console, i manage to send to everyone, without problem
Is there a way to achieve the same results from app ?

P.s. 
naturally if I add

```
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:@"Mychannel"];
[push setMessage:@"Invio Push"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

the push notification is sent correctly to "Mychannel" channel

Many thanks
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also send push notifications directly from a mobile application. Remember that you need to have enabled this feature in the Parse app's settings tab by selecting "Yes" under the heading "Client push enabled?". There are several methods that can be called to send push notifications.

My Example:

```
// Create our Installation query
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];

// Send push notification to query
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery 
                               withMessage:@"TEST1234"];
```

Comment: Hi,this is not what i requested. I know that i can send push notification from app, and i did. The only problem is that i manage to send only to channel and not to everybody. Tks anyway